# Alternate UIView background between two colors by pressing a button

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

I'm trying to set up one button that each time pressed would alternate between two colours (black and white).
Initially the app loads with a black background, with the first button tap it swaps to a white background, with the second tap it swaps back to a black background and so fourth.

I imagine it would be a simple if else statement, however I don't know how to create a variable that is the current UI background colour.

```
@IBAction func background_toggle(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
}
```

The button swaps it to white, but there isn't any implementation to swap back to black when there is a second press.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `backgroundColor` as a condition to check which one you should pick next.

---

**Approach using a backgroundColor attribute**

```swift
@IBAction func background_toggle(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if self.view.backgroundColor == .white {
        self.view.backgroundColor = .black
    } else {
        self.view.backgroundColor = .white
    }
}
```

In other words: If `backgroundColor` is `.white`, then set it `.black`

Otherwise, set it `.white`

---

**Tips:**

Since `backgroundColor` is an `UIColor`, Swift infers the type, so you can just type `.white` or `.black` when assigning it,  without having to specify `UIColor.white` or `UIColor.black`.

You can have a state variable like a `Bool`, `UIColor` or `Enum`. Then you compare to that instead of the `backgroundColor` of the view.

---

**Approach using a Bool variable**

```swift
var isWhite = true

@objc func handleOpenTermsAndConditions() {

    if self.isWhite {
        self.isWhite = false
        self.view.backgroundColor = .black
    } else {
        self.isWhite = true
        self.view.backgroundColor = .white
    }
}
```

---

**Approach using an UIColor variable**

```swift
var currentBackgroundColor : UIColor = .white

@objc func handleOpenTermsAndConditions() {

    if currentBackgroundColor == .white {
        self.currentBackgroundColor = .black
        self.view.backgroundColor = .black
    } else {
        self.currentBackgroundColor = .white
        self.view.backgroundColor = .white
    }
}
```

---

**Approach using an Enum state**

If you want to restrict colors you can create an `Enum` with available colors. I think it's overkill to use it with some logic that is as simple as `.white` | `.black`.

Step 1: Create an `enum`.

```swift
enum AvailableColor {
    case white
    case black

    func currentUIColor() -> UIColor {
        switch self {
        case .white:
            return UIColor.white
        case .black:
            return UIColor.black
        }
    }
}
```

Step 2: Instantiate a state variable and use the `enum` logic

```swift
var currentColorState : AvailableColor = .white

@objc func handleOpenTermsAndConditions() {

    if currentColorState == .white {
        currentColorState = .black
    } else {
        currentColorState = .white
    }

    self.view.backgroundColor = currentColorState.currentUIColor()
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Any one more, if I wanted to save the current background colour as a variable. How would i do this? (This is more out of interest)

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to use the contents of the view to determine the next state by comparing the colors.

Separate out your **model** from your **view** and keep a separate property that has the current state. You could use a simple boolean flag `isBlack`, or you could create an enumeration:

```
enum BackgroundState {
    case black, white
}
```

which has the slight advantage of being easier to expand if you ever want another color/state. (`CaseIterable` might be helpful then as well.)